# database outputs in xml/rss file

Tags: php, sql, xml, rss

So im trying to show my feeds from the file feed.php (its rss) on my frontpage index.php..
But its like it cant read my inputs 'item' 'title' etc from feed.php when i load it to the index.php.... however, there doesnt seem to be any trouble in feed.php itself

Index.php i have following code

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('feed.php');
$counter = 0;
$amount = 5;
foreach($feed->channel->item as $item){
 while ($counter<$amount) {
  echo utf8_decode("<a href='{$item->link}'>{$item->title}</a><br>");
  echo utf8_decode("<i>{$item->pubDate} </i><br>"); 
  echo utf8_decode("{$item->description} <br><br>");
 break;
 } 
$counter ++;
}
```

And this in feed.php

```
<rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
  <title>This is the title</title>
   <link>http://www.someweirdurl.com</link>
   <description>Just a testpage</description>
   <?php
   require_once 'dbconn.php';

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM feeds";
   $obj_result = $obj_con->query($sql);
   while ($row = $obj_result->fetch_object()) { 
   ?>
    <item>
     <title><?php echo $row->artikel_title; ?></title>
     <link><?php echo $row->artikel_url; ?></link>
     <description><?php echo $row->artikel_tekst; ?></description>
     <author><?php echo $row->artikel_forfatter; ?></author>
     <category><?php echo $row->artikel_kategori; ?></category>
     <subDate>Fri, 05 Jul 2013 15:29:07 +0200</subDate>
    </item>
   <?php 
   }  
   ?>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

I tried to print it on index.php and it gives me outputs like

```
[author] => SimpleXMLElement Object
```

Its like they are empty..
While it get the subDate (as the only one)

```
[subDate] => Fri, 05 Jul 2013 15:29:07 +0200
```

Probably due to subDate is the only one i didnt take out from the database..
So what do i have to make different to make it work with data from my database..?

Answer (score 1):

if feed.php , u must put **all the xml strings in a variable** like $my_xml ,

then **after php codes** , use `header ("Content-Type:text/xml");`    to change the file type into xml.

then echo the $my_xml .

just it